# change header view on small screen

Tags: html, css, jsx

I have a header which looks like this :

[image]

I found an example of what I wan. On small screen i need the search bar to go underneath.:
[image]

The issue is that i have no idea how this is done. I tried changing the position to relative when i reach a certain screen width but this didn't help.

```
  <div className="header">
    <div className="header__logo">
      <img src={logo} alt=""></img>
    </div>
    <div className="header__search">
      <SearchBar />
    </div>
    <div className="header__right">
      <FiUser className="header__icon" />
      <Cart />
    </div>
  </div>



/*
   header
*/
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__logo {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 65px;
}

.header__logo img {
  width: 120px;
  background-size: contain;
}

.header__search {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header__right {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__icon {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I dont need you to code it for me i'm fine doing that myself, I just have no clue how to go on about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One option would be to create two `search bars` in the same file. And hide one and show other depending on screen sizes.

Somthing like this:

```
<select class="for-desktop"> ... </select>
<select class="for-mobile"> ... </select>
```

Then CSS would look like following:

```
 @media(max-width:768px){
     .for-desktop{
        display:none;
      }
 }

 @media(min-width:768px){
     .for-mobile{
        display:none;
      }
 }
```

This way you don't need to think too much other stuff. This will simpy do it.

2. Other way is to use CSS-Grid for the Entire Header. And show the `select` on the bottom (Need to write some code efficiently)
3. You can do one quick hack also. Set `position:relative` on the `parent` and `position:absolute;` for the select only when screen size is smaller and adjust your `select` accordingly.

Something Like the below example.

```
.header {
  position:relative;
}

.header__search {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -60px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

(You may need to do small adjustments with positioning of `search` item)

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a little css refactor, you can use CSS grid to change the position of this search bar

For more info i would recommend this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Cheers!

-- UPDATE ---

if not, you can hide this bar when your screen side reach some point and then show a new "div" or a "copy" right below (I think it can be cool and
easier to create animations)

or even use javascript to append this element to the desired position